# Navigate to /ect on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have tried quite hard to navigate into the ect directory in the root directory, but I constantly get the error: no such file or directory. Anyone know why this could be. This is my second day on Linux, so this might be super easy..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's /etc, not /ect .  Also this question is not programming related, so belongs on SuperUser or the Ubuntu StackExchange site.

Comment: Holy cow. that was it. I can't believe myself.. ha!

Answer (score 2):

The directory is /etc.  I've gone looking for the wrong directory myself.